# LotusNotes best way to get user input from Dialogbox with images

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I would like to have an (lotusscript)Agent open a Dialog Box with images and get a return from some sort of selection (combobox...).

I thought about making a Dialog Form but I need Input directly and not through a document if possible.

I couldn't figure out how to put images into a simple InputBox.

Does anyone have a solution (if possible without including an extra Dialog form)?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you are asking: There is no "image selection dialog box" in Notes. Where do you want to select the images from? From image resources? From Windows explorer? What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? As is this question will be closed as to broad / unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put images in a simple inputbox. NotesUiWorkspace.prompt is just too limitied for that. You should be able to use a dialog box subform/form for this.

What do you mean by "you need input directly" ? You could just use the current open document with your dialogbox form and you should have the field filled in. Depends wether you prefer script or @Formulas..